# TFS release management, .net core rc2 deployment to on-premise servers

Tags: asp.net-core, tfs, azure-devops, .net-core-rc2

New to Visual Studio Team Services, previously Visual Studio Online

I have a couple .net core rc2 apps.

Example 1: Solution contains 1 .net core MVC app, 1 Web Api app, Multiple dependent assemblies.

I've got 3 on-premise servers (Dev, QA, Staging)
My dev server contains the build agent. My confusion is on how to best deploy these apps to my on-premise servers and finally to my production server on azure.

Do I generate webdeploy packages? If so, where and with what? In my build definition or release definition (on tfs)?

What would be the proper way to do the deployment part of these .net core rc2 apps and (using what, and in what order) is what im trying to figure out.

To my understanding so far, I believe on check in (CI build), I build/deploy to all 3 environments (dev, qa, staging). With dev and qa being automatic. Staging being either automatic or approved (authorized), depending on QA results. Finally production, being manual. I understand this is not set in stone, and certain things can be done differently, but does it sound right?

Oh, and all my servers are windows server 2012 r2

Answer (score 0):

You can use build definition to build your project and generate the deployment packages and then use release definition to deploy the packages. In the release definition, you can add three environment to deploy to Dev, QA & Staging. For how to build and deploy Asp.Net Core app, please refer to this link for details: [Build and deploy your ASP.NET Core RC2 app to Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure#define-a-deployment-build).